# How can I update Observable, which used in async pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Problem is that: I have simple component, which renders some "history" of messages. When app is loaded, it makes POST-request, gets data and sets data to Observable like this

```
this.messages$ = Observable.of(messagesAfterPOSTRequest);
```

where `public messages$: Observable<any>;`

This data is rendered in template via async pipe:

```
let message of messages$ | async
```

It works good, but ....

I get some "new messages" via websocket, so I would like to update the list, which was created on previous step. I am trying to use `scan()`

```
this.messages$ = this.messages$.scan((accMessage, numMessage) => {
        console.log("inside current mesages", accMessage, numMessage)
      });
```

In order to "update" current list messages, but this console.logs looks like never work, even with subscribe()

Comment: Are you sure you want to assign `this.messages$` here: `this.messages$ = this.messages$.scan(...)`?

Comment: Probably, inside of scan() ?

Comment: You can use a subject as described in the answer below, or create `messages$` as `this.messages$ = Observable.webSocket(apiURL)`

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance of `Subject` and push messages into it:

```
const subject$ = new Subject();

...

subject.next(messagesAfterPOSTRequest);
```

... then use it a template the same way using `async` pipe.

Maybe also have a look at `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` classes if you want to be able to get previous messages as well.

Comment: Problem is at start I have list of messages and it's works subject.next(messagesAfterPOSTRequest);

but when I get only one message - I get list from one messages, history is removed after next()

Comment: Then use the `.scan` operator and add the messages to an array: `.scan((acc, val) => { acc.push(val); return val;}, [])`